# C# mysql 75 mile radius map covering the entire US

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have a database full of zipcodes and their lat/long.  What i want to do is to be able to cover the entire US in 75 mile radius circles with as little overlap as possible.  Any hints or tips?  My intentions are to cover the entire US in 75 mile circles with as little overlap as possible, essentially i want to know all zipcodes that are 150 miles from each other starting in the middle of the country towards the coasts.

What i'm trying to say is I need to make sure that I have 75 mile circles cover the entire US, essentially that I can not miss any zipcodes.  So if i started in Kansas and I moved out, I would have 75 mile circles overlapping maybe in 10 miles increments until all of the us in covered.

Kind of like this map http://modernsurvivalblog.com/pictures/usa-survival-location-map-300-mile-zones-not-safe-with-population-more-than-100-thousand-1433x975.jpg

However, that map does radius's around 100k population.  I want to just start at a specific lat/long and cover the entire US.

Comment: Start with the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for calculating your distances.

Comment: Is this a college homework problem? I don't mind if it is or not, it just seems like a totally bizarre thing to want to do!

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the zipcode lat/lon database to your desire to cover the entire US with circles of radius 75 miles with as little overlap as possible. Maybe you haven't described your intentions clearly enough. E.g. Do you want to make sure each major metro area is the centerpoint of such a circle? For each zipcode, do you want to get a list of all other zipcodes whose centroids are within 75 miles of the starting zipcode's centroid? That would cause overlap.

Comment: No my intentions are to cover the entire US in 75 mile circles with as little overlap as possible, essentially i want to know all zipcodes that are 150 miles from each other starting in the middle of the country towards the coasts without getting any zipcodes in between those points

Comment: @Mike: do you have a lat/lon pair for the centroid of the zipcode, or many lat/lon pairs for the outline of the zipcode? Zipcodes have irregular shapes. Do you want to know all zipcodes whose boundaries are completely inside the circle? Partly inside the circle? Zipcodes whose centroids are within the circle? "Those points" -- what "points"? You need to chose your terms carefully when discussing geospatial stuff.

Comment: Yeah i'm have the lat/long please see edit ill try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can try overlaying the map with a square grid with each grid square being 106 miles by 106 miles.  Then create your circles based on the center of the grid square with your 75 mile radius which should be very close to the vertices of the square intersecting the perimeter of the circle.  I don't know if this will give you the absolute minimum overlap but is a starting point that provides 100% coverage of the area.